# How to get Properties from an Element of the ShadowDOM of my Component

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get the value of the attribute "checked" of the input Element which is in the ShadowDOM.

```js
class BitBoxComponent extends HTMLElement {
  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["checked"];
  }

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.inputElem = document.createElement("INPUT");
    this.inputElem.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    this.inputElem.setAttribute("checked", false);

    //    this.inputElem.style.border = "solid 1px grey";

    const style = document.createElement("style");
    style.textContent = ``;

    const shadow = this.attachShadow({
      mode: "open"
    });
    shadow.appendChild(style);
    shadow.appendChild(this.inputElem);
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (oldValue === newValue) return;
    var isTrueSet = newValue == "true";
    this.inputElem.checked = isTrueSet;

  }
}

customElements.define("bit-box", BitBoxComponent);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const bit = document.getElementById("bit-7").getAttribute("checked");
  console.log(bit);
})
```

```html
<bit-box id="bit-7"></bit-box>
<bit-box id="bit-6"></bit-box>
<bit-box id="bit-0"></bit-box>
<!--    https://github.com/mateusortiz/webcomponents-the-right-way -->
```

after a click on the checkbox the value of the attribute "checked" should change.
And then I want to get the value to work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, when you use `mode: 'open'` there is no need to store a reference - it is automatically available in `this.shadowRoot` (also from the outside).

Next, create a getter and setter for `checked`, which make `checked` behave like a true **Boolean attribute**:

```js
class BitBoxComponent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.inputElem = document.createElement("INPUT");
    this.inputElem.type = "checkbox";
    this.inputElem.checked = false;
    this.inputElem.addEventListener('change', () => {
      this.checked = this.inputElem.checked;
    })

    this.attachShadow({
      mode: "open"
    });
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(this.inputElem);
  }

  static get observedAttributes() {
    return ["checked"];
  }

  attributeChangedCallback(name, oldValue, newValue) {
    if (oldValue === newValue) return;
    if (oldValue === null) { // attribute was added
      this.inputElem.checked = true;
    } else if (newValue === null) { // attribute was removed
      this.inputElem.checked = false;
    }
    const event = new CustomEvent('bit-box-change', {
      detail: {
        checked: this.checked
      }
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(event);
  }

  get checked() {
    return this.inputElem.checked;
  }

  set checked(bool) {
    if (bool) {
      this.setAttribute('checked', '');
    } else {
      this.removeAttribute('checked')
    }
  }
}

customElements.define("bit-box", BitBoxComponent);

document.querySelectorAll('bit-box').forEach(box => 
  box.addEventListener('bit-box-change', (event) => {
    console.log(event.detail.checked);
  })
);
```

```html
<bit-box id="bit-7"></bit-box>
<bit-box id="bit-6"></bit-box>
<bit-box id="bit-0"></bit-box>
<!--    https://github.com/mateusortiz/webcomponents-the-right-way -->
```

How the attribute works: Boolean attributes like `checked`,  `disabled`, `hidden` work like this: The actual `value` of the attribute is ***irrelevant***. The **presence** of the attribute means `true`, the **absence** means false.

Also note that on regular checkboxes, the attribute `checked` does only ever reflect the *initial state* of the checkbox. When it changes, this is not reflected to the attribute! What you're really interested in is not the `checked` ***attribute***, but the `checked` ***property***.